# Short way to do os.path.join()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, os.path

I'm really tired of typing `os.path.join()` each time I have to construct a path and I was thinking of defining a shortcut like this one:

```
def pj(*args):
    from os.path import join
    return join(args)
```

But it throws `TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'tuple'`

So I wonder what is the correct way to pass arguments to `os.path.join()` and all in all, am I trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You shouldn't `import` inside the function. Why not just `from os.path import join` wherever you're using it? Then you don't have to type `os.path.` and it's only two letters longer (not to mention more readable, and more likely to be something anyone reading your code already knows about).

Comment: I would put the import outside of the function. It will get executed none the less when you import your helper function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *unpack* the arguments to `.join`:

```
join(*args)
#    ^
```

Like so:

```
>>> import os.path.join
>>> args = ('/usr/main/', 'etc/negate/')
>>> os.path.join(*args)
'/usr/main/etc/negate/'
```

P.S.: Using `import` in your function isn't a very good idea. Move it to the top of your module.

Comment: @MatthiasSchreiber Yes it could. Depends on how familiar people can get with such short form: `numpy -> np`, `pandas -> pd`, why not.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Python 3.4, you could give [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) a try.

From the doc:

```
>>> p = Path('/etc')
>>> q = p / 'init.d' / 'reboot'
>>> q
PosixPath('/etc/init.d/reboot')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rename it in the import statement:

```
from os.path import join as pj # or whatever other name you pick 
                               # to distinguish it from str.join
```